# Graph doesn't show when axes are scaled

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a plot with three different graphs in it. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_sequence(N:int, alpha:float, beta:float) -> np.ndarray:
    z_n = np.empty((N, 1))
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        z_n[n-1] = alpha*(1+sqrt(3))**n + beta*(1-sqrt(3))**n
    return z_n

x0 = make_sequence(50, 0.0, 1.0)
x1 = make_sequence(50, 0.0, 99.0)
x2 = make_sequence(50, 5.0, 5.0)

plt.plot(x0, 'bo')
plt.plot(x1, 'ro')
plt.plot(x2, 'go')
plt.axis([0, 50, -2, 2])
plt.title(r'$z_1,...,z_{50}$')
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.legend([r'$\alpha =0$,  $\beta =1$', r'$\alpha =0$,  $\beta =99$', r'$\alpha =5$,  $\beta =5$'])
plt.show()
```

Why does x2 not show up on the plot?
If I try to plot x2 alone it only shows if I remove the axis-scaling command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing `min(x2)` and `max(x2)` shows that `x2` ranges from `10` to `~3.3e22`. However, your y axis only goes from `-2`  to `2`. Hence none of the values from `x2` are in the visible range.

You may of course change the scale to `plt.axis([0, 50, -2, 3.5e22])`, which would result in

[image]

But then, `x0` and `x1` are not well seen in the plot anymore. You need to decide for yourself, if it makes sense to plot all 3 series in the same plot.